# Kotlinx.kover - randomly failing unit tests

Tags: android, kotlin, kover

Just after adding kover to the project

```
classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kover:${PluginVersions.kover}")

apply plugin: 'kover'
```

the unit tests randomly start to fail (however they run without any failures without kover in the project). I even tried disabling failing tests, but just more and more random fails keep appearing.

We use classic kotlin.test.Test tests and some libs to help with testing (io.mockk.mockk).

Any idea what could cause this?

Kover Gradle Plugin version: 0.6.1

Gradle version: 7.4.2

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:196)
at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:177)
at net.bytebuddy.jar.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:163)
at net.bytebuddy.utility.OpenedClassReader.of(OpenedClassReader.java:86)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default$ForInlining.create(TypeWriter.java:3824)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default.make(TypeWriter.java:2166)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.inline.RedefinitionDynamicTypeBuilder.make(RedefinitionDynamicTypeBuilder.java:224)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.inline.AbstractInliningDynamicTypeBuilder.make(AbstractInliningDynamicTypeBuilder.java:123)
at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase.make(DynamicType.java:3595)
at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.transformation.InliningClassTransformer.transform(InliningClassTransformer.kt:78)
at java.instrument/java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(ClassFileTransformer.java:244)
at java.instrument/sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:541)
at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)
at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:169)
at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.transformation.JvmInlineInstrumentation.retransform(JvmInlineInstrumentation.kt:28)
at io.mockk.proxy.common.transformation.RetransformInlineInstrumnetation$execute$1.invoke(RetransformInlineInstrumnetation.kt:19)
at io.mockk.proxy.common.transformation.RetransformInlineInstrumnetation$execute$1.invoke(RetransformInlineInstrumnetation.kt:6)
at io.mockk.proxy.common.transformation.ClassTransformationSpecMap.applyTransformation(ClassTransformationSpecMap.kt:41)
at io.mockk.proxy.common.transformation.RetransformInlineInstrumnetation.execute(RetransformInlineInstrumnetation.kt:16)
at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.ProxyMaker.inline(ProxyMaker.kt:88)
at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.ProxyMaker.proxy(ProxyMaker.kt:30)
at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmMockFactory.newProxy(JvmMockFactory.kt:34)
at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.AbstractMockFactory.newProxy$default(AbstractMockFactory.kt:29)
at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.AbstractMockFactory.mockk(AbstractMockFactory.kt:59)
at packagename.base.user.web.repository.UserWebMergeRepositoryTest$test$1.invokeSuspend(UserWebMergeRepositoryTest.kt:89)
at packagename.base.user.web.repository.UserWebMergeRepositoryTest$test$1.invoke(UserWebMergeRepositoryTest.kt)
at packagename.base.user.web.repository.UserWebMergeRepositoryTest$test$1.invoke(UserWebMergeRepositoryTest.kt)
at packagename.base.utils.test.TestUtilsKt$runWithTimeout$1$1.invokeSuspend(TestUtils.kt:11)
at packagename.base.utils.test.TestUtilsKt$runWithTimeout$1$1.invoke(TestUtils.kt)
at packagename.base.utils.test.TestUtilsKt$runWithTimeout$1$1.invoke(TestUtils.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturnIgnoreTimeout(Undispatched.kt:100)
at kotlinx.coroutines.TimeoutKt.setupTimeout(Timeout.kt:146)
at kotlinx.coroutines.TimeoutKt.withTimeout(Timeout.kt:44)
at packagename.base.utils.test.TestUtilsKt$runWithTimeout$1.invokeSuspend(TestUtils.kt:11)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:284)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:85)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:59)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:38)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
at packagename.base.utils.test.TestUtilsKt.runWithTimeout(TestUtils.kt:11)
at packagename.base.utils.test.TestUtilsKt.runWithTimeout$default(TestUtils.kt:8)
at packagename.base.user.web.repository.UserWebMergeRepositoryTest.test(UserWebMergeRepositoryTest.kt:25)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:108)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:40)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:60)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:52)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$2.run(TestWorker.java:176)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
```